# Image not showing in an archive page

Tags: images

Below each custom post I have two images and a title and excerpt of other posts to read, but the images aren't loading. If I look at the code I see that the image variable is empty.

```
<?php
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent_post ) {
        setup_postdata( $recent_post );
        $image_id   = get_post_thumbnail_id( $recent_post->ID );
        $image_url  = '';
        if( $image_id > 0 ) {
            $image_url    = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id, 'medium' );
        }

?>
```

Should the `$image_url` be empty?

Comment: I'm not a php programmer but in the code above you are setting image_url to empty, which is fine but then there is an if clause. Is the if clause satisfied so statement after it is executed?

Comment: The problem is not in the code you posted.. Is the image correctly printed in html..?

Comment: I agree, the problem could be with the conditional check, or anywhere else in your (unposted) code...

Answer (score 1):

Most of this code is unnecessary. Remove everything inside the `foreach` from your question and just use:

```
foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent_post ) {
    $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent_post, 'medium' );
    // etc.
}
```